# Is it a good idea to use PHP's REMOTE_ADDR variable to verify a download?

Tags: php, paypal, ip

So I have a site that let's you buy and download mp3's. The mp3's are all made by me. But when the user goes through the PayPal checkout process (I have buttons and IPN all setup already) my IPN script stores the order ID as well as the IP address of where the user bought the MP3 from. The IPN script generates a download link and emails that link to the users PayPal email.

So whenever the user clicks the download link, it takes the user to my download page. On the download page, it finds the download ID in the database as well as the order ID, the MP3 ID, and the IP Address the user was on when they purchased the MP3. Is it a good idea for me to have to verify the databases IP Address with the users current IP Address and let the user download it? I store the IP Address using:

`getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')` in PHP.

Or should I just skip any verification and let anyone who clicks on that link download the file?

Answer (score 0):

alright, first of all you should think about the logic behind your question.

just as an example:

an user buys a song from your site. first question should be, if you allow him to access this download link temporarily (1,2,3 hours, days...) or is it just once possible to call that download link or is it lifetime garanteed that this user has access to it.

after you have set this basic information you can go ahead.

case 1 (temporarily access):
storing $_REMOTE_ADDR is a good beginning but what in case this user sits behind a vpn network, in a lan and so on... there are some more ways. you should read about HTTP_CLIENT_IP, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, HTTP_X_FORWARDED... and so on!

you even should have in mind that all $_SERVER attributes can be manipulated. So just as an advise: you should sanitize all variables before storing them into your database instead of trusting them blindly.

back to the issue: you have stored now the ip, for security reasons, okay. maybe you fear to get cheated. doesn't matter. your script generates a download-link that will be sent to the paypals email address. now you have two options:

**first:** an user has already verified through paypal and everthing is fine. so you dont need to fear anything.

in this case you should think of delimiting the time that an user has acces to your files. now imagine this user has a few million friends and you would be justin timberlake for example, than the user would sent the link that he has received to all of his friends that would try to access your server and download your files - assumed your servers hardware would do so!

so first of all a better way is to delimit the time to access the link for example for 1,2,3 hours... after buying - still not perfect but this would avoid the above.

If you restrict it further to the IP - assumed you will learn how to get that the right way - an user just can download your mp3s from the IP address where he bought it from. what when the user has a smartphone and wants to download it from anywhere else than home? am i right, that the users have to create an account to use your offers?

than the solution could be to store the frequency that a mp3 has downloaded by a certain user. here you could set a limit to 50 times, that should be quiet much for one song to download again and again and again.... you even get an overview if an user will be logged once or has this user published his login data for illegal sharing issues.

**seccond:** an user has not verified through paypal and tries to cheat on you. imagine he will create an account at paypal and leaves incorrect bank/account information. paypal would pay you first and tries to regain the money afterwards from an incorrect account information. when paypal has recognized that the information left in the user account are wrong they surely will cancel the whole transaction and regain it from your account. in the end you`ll be always the loser when accepting paypal. sorry.

and to be quiet honest to yourself: how are the chances to catch some people that try to cheat on you?! 0,0000000032423 percent maybe with an the whole risk on your site to lose much money for pursuing investigations.